# LENGUAJE PASCAL A LENGUAJE C

Tags: c, pascal

Escribir un programa en C, que escriba los números comprendidos entre 1 y 100. El programa
escribirá en la pantalla los números en grupos de 20, solicitando al usuario si quiere o no
continuar visualizando el siguiente grupo de números.
Hola, es la primera vez que utilizo C en mi vida y no sé cómo establecer las sentencias, hasta ahora solo he hecho el conteo del 1 al 100 pero no en grupos de 20, ni con opciones :C

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código en C que he hecho hasta el momento:

```
#include <stdio.h> //--> PrintF, quich
int main(void){
  int i, a=0;
  printf("\t\tNumeros del 1 al 100\n");
  printf("\t\t--------------------\n\n");

  for(i=1; i<=100; i++){
 if(i<=20){
   printf("");
}
    if(i<=9){
      printf("0");
    }
    printf(  "%i, ",i);
    a++;
    while(a==10) {
      printf("\n");
      a=0;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Por favor muestra el código, lo que has intentado y qué errores o comportamiento no esperado tiene.

Comment: hola, ya añadí la imagen, perdón y gracias :)

Comment: Código, escribe código porque a algunos usuarios se les dificulta la lectura de las imágenes por sus dispositivos

Comment: @ang3les96, ya lo hice muchas gracias

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta porque es una solicitud para que se le resuelva una tarea escolar sin demostrar esfuerzo.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>
    int main(void){
        int continuar = 1; //la variable continuar indica si se mostrará el siguiente bloque
        int i, j;

        j = 1; //La variable j determina el número a imprimir
        while ((continuar==1)&&(j<100)){ //mientras continuar sea igual a 1 y j menor a 100 haz...
            for (i=j; i<j+20; i++){
                printf ("%d\n", i);
            }
            
            j = i; //Se actualiza el valor de j y se pregunta si se desea mostrar el siguiente bloque
            
            printf ("Desea continuar 1:SI; 0:NO ");
            
            scanf ("%d", &continuar);
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Te hacía falta acomodar los ciclos, en este caso el `for` está dentro del `while`, por otra parte, te recomiendo buscar información sobre fundamentos de programación, algoritmos, diagramas de flujo a lo que posteriormente aprenderás sobre pseudocódigo. Si la *programación* es algo que te apasiona, entonces investiga sobre los fundamentos, poco a poco te irás interesando en algo específico.

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por tu ayuda de verdad, estoy muy interesado en programar pero me he dedicado más a desarrollo web, estoy en 5to ciclo de la universidad, pero por la pandemia no he aprendido nada, los profesores no me han enseñado nada, si queria aprender algo tenia que hacerlo por mi cuenta y yo aprendo cuando practico, de verdad muchas gracias y que Dios te bendiga, cuidate mucho y gracias por tu apoyo

Comment: Si te sirvió mi respuesta puedes "aceptarla" y, bueno, nunca está de más ser autodidacta. Éxitos :)

Answer (score 0):

Talvez quieras una solución mas simple en cantidad de código, el for aquí toma el rango entre el mínimo y el máximo que le des incluyendo el máximo, de ahí el `<=` y lo imprimes, después de eso lo fácil es sacar el resto entre el numero de la posición (tiene un +1 porque 0/n es falso); piénsalo como "es esa posición multiple de la cantidad por fila", si lo es salta de line, sino, sigue.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int arg_c, char * arg_v []){

    if (arg_c != 4){
        printf("main.exe min max alineo \n");
        return 1;
    }

    int i, min, max, len;
    min = atoi(arg_v[1]);
    max = atoi(arg_v[2]);
    len = atoi(arg_v[3]);

    for(i = min; i <= max; i++){

        // El 3 indica los espacios de margen
        printf("%3i", i);

        if((i - min + 1) % len){
            printf(", ");
        } else {
            printf("\n");
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

```
> main.exe  9 123 12
```

El `if` parece que no tenga condición pero tiene una implícita, comparando con `(lo que le des) != NULL` a si que `~(0)` será cierto.

Lo de antes del for es un poco de relleno para probar varias veces sin recompilar, y si compilas con c11 o mayor pues usar `int x = 0;` o `for (int i = 0;...`

Comment: No es la solución exacta del problema descrito, es parametrizada claro y abarca esa descripción como otras. Sin embargo, carece de validaciones para casos como max < min, len = 0,... etc. **Este programa falla si se equivoca el orden de los parámetros** o con las condiciones anteriores. Si realmente deseamos colaborar al OP y este ha hecho su mejor intento,  dar la respuesta más simple posible y comentar para darle otras opciones de mejoras.

Comment: @DEVX75 si pruebas el ejemplo, veras que `max < min` funciona y `len < 0` también funciona, solo falla si le pasas texto en vez de un numero. Pero creo que el ejemplo encaja con el `simple en cantidad de código`

Comment: main.exe 123 9 12 
=>
for(i= 123; i <= 9;  i++)  //No itera

main.exe 9 120 0
=>
(i - 9 + 1) % 0   // DIV entre cero, en todos los casos de i

Comment: Fallo mio, me confundí con otra cosa, pero aun así, tu crees que op quería 100 líneas de  condiciones para las 10 que es la función ?. Te parecería mejor si el ejemplo tuviera min/max/len como constantes ?